# how to do horton analyis on single catchment in grass gis

Tags: grass-gis

I have generated streams using r.stream.extract and used r.stream.order
then I have tun r.stream.basin using inputs from r.stream.order. I am getting multiple basins. How to select a single basin and calculate the horton statistics on single catchment area.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the number of the catchment you want to work on with the query tool in the graphical user interface or r.what and then use [r.mask](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.mask.html) to restrict the computation to only this catchment.

Subsequent computations with then only consider this part of the data. With r.mask -r you can eventually remove the MASK later.